# Visual Studio 2017 propfull snippet but with .this

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-snippets

Hello i use the propfull snippet in VS a lot but i always have to add .this every time since the shortcut does not include it. Any idea where i can find a snippet that does that(for VS 2017 without resharper). I searched but the best i could find was a resharper version and that does not work for me. Sorry if this was posted somewhere but i could not find an answer.

Examples:

Normal propfull:

```
    private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return myVar; }
        set { myVar = value; }
    }
```

Desired propfull:

```
    private int myVar;

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return this.myVar; }
        set { this.myVar = value; }
    }
```

Comment: In all honesty, if you are only returning the backing field, don't create your own backing field, vs does that for you, in C# 6 you can even use them as readonly backing fields so that you can set them from inside the constructor (so you would only define `public int MyProperty { get; }`

Comment: Why do you even want this. ?

Comment: yes i agree with you on that but most of the time i have to do some kind of validation in the setter and i prefer to use this.someName for a more clean approach :)

Comment: You do know that resharper will mark the `this` as redundant?

Comment: Currently not  using resharper, but correct me if i am wrong , the usage of this. is kind of a personal preference at least for me.

Comment: @StoyanGrigorov Sure, I am just pointing out that this is not really a preference for most people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using the snippet manager that you can find in Visual Studio, under Tools -> Code snippet manager...

[image]

I took for example the propfull implementation of the Microsoft snippet, and just changed it slightly so that it will add this in front of the properties, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<CodeSnippets  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>propfull with this</Title>
      <Shortcut>thispropfull</Shortcut>
      <Description>Code snippet for property and backing field</Description>
      <Author>Icepickle</Author>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal>
          <ID>type</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property type</ToolTip>
          <Default>int</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>property</ID>
          <ToolTip>Property name</ToolTip>
          <Default>MyProperty</Default>
        </Literal>
        <Literal>
          <ID>field</ID>
          <ToolTip>The variable backing this property</ToolTip>
          <Default>myVar</Default>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[private $type$ $field$;

  public $type$ $property$
  {
    get { return this.$field$;}
    set { this.$field$ = value;}
  }
  $end$]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

You can save this file as your own snippet (extension .snippet), and then use the import button to add your own snippet. Then you can write the shortcut `thispropfull` and it would create the desired snippet

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is what i wanted! :) You are awesome :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)